# failing to scrape entire page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code loops through the page but doesn't completely loop through the entire page,stopping usually at the 6 or 7th race at the meeting in the race.Can anyone suggest why BS is failing here.This is the url http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135549

```
 from urllib import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 baseURL = 'http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135549'
 html = urlopen(baseURL)
 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

 nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlockHeader"})
 for i in nameList:


 nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "track"})
 for j in nameList1:
     print(j.get_text())

 nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "date"})
 for j in nameList1:
     print(j.get_text())

 nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "datetime"})
 for j in nameList1:
     print(j.get_text())

 nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "grade"})
 for j in nameList1:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "distance"})
for j in nameList1:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "prizes"})
for j in nameList1:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlock"})
for i in nameList:

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())

nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
for j in nameList2:
    print(j.get_text())
```

python web-scraping bs4

Comment: Problem is with your connectivity, try using higher speed internet

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code working as depicted.  However, using

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

I was able to run the rest of the code just fine, after fixing some indentation.  Note the `.request`.

I can see 13 race results on the web page when I use a browser and I get 13 race results using your BS code.

Your BS code is working.  So we just need to look at any issues prior to BS being called.  And the only possible line to cause an issue is `html = urlopen(baseURL)`.  Perhaps you're dealing with some connectivity issues.

I'm guessing you are double checking against what's publicly presented on the web page, right?  I suspect the # of races varies over time so obtaining 6 or 7 results might be all of them.

Comment: Hi hfuhruhurr.Many thanks for the reply,and I think you must be right about the problem being up top,however when I replace the above with your urllib code i get "import error  no module named request".When I look in pycharms settings it tells me that request is installed,so I tried notebook++ but got the same message.I am going to re-install request,have you any other suggestionsmany thanks Moon

Comment: I would go raw to deduce the issue.  That is, just start a python session from a terminal window.  Type `from urllib.request import urlopen` and hit return.  If you have no issues, then it's something with your PyCharms/Notepad++ setup.  (Note:  the code for the `urlopen` functionality is in a file called "request.py" somewhere in your installation.  You can't use `urlopen` without it.)

Comment: By any chance, is your code file named "urllib.py"?  I found out the hard way that you shouldn't use "csv.py" as a file name if you use the "csv" module within.  I guess Python thinks your csv.py is the csv module to be invoked.

Comment: Hi hfuhruhurr,I did what you suggested and there were no issues when I opened it in terminal window,so it could be an issue with pycharm or ++.Could you tell me what framework you used to get the code working?

Comment: I am still working on this and seem to have a problem with the request(not requests) library.I have installed pip bs4 and lxml,but when I go to run the code i get" from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request".I seem to have all the right stuff installed,any suggestions appreciated.Moonshadow

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me after a fix a few tiny indent issues.